# JSP 2.0 - using tag files in a JSP document without .tld declaration

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I want to use something like this in my **jsp document** files:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
```

However, in all the 30+ examples I've seen, everyone uses simple jsp syntax, not jsp document syntax. Something like this:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
    xmlns:t="/WEB-INF/tags" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    version="2.0">
```

simply does not work. All the tag files which reside in /WEB-INF/tags aren't seen on the page. Only if I define a tld file, and list all the tags there, they can be accessed on the page. Is it possible to avoid tld declaration and still use tag files in a jsp document page?

Answer (score 6):

1 Create tags directory in your WEB-INF/ directory

2 Create sample.tag file where your tag will be:

```
<%@ attribute name="exampleAttribute" required="true" type="java.lang.String" description="Example attribute" %>

<c:out value="${exampleAttribute}">
```

3 Declare tag library at you jsp where you want to use it:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
```

4 Use it:

```
<tags:sample exampleAttribute="Hello from custom tag!"/>
```

And I think you should have version of web application 2.5. Think only from that version JSP 2.0 is supported (check in web.xml).

Comment: JSP pages and documents have different syntax. You used the page syntax, but I need the equivalent of 
`<%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>` written in the jsp document syntax (which is in pure xml). If I use your statement in my document, I simply get an exception, since it is not a valid code for jsp document.

Comment: Works great for me!!

Answer (score 6):

You need to put the prefix "urn:jsptagdir:" in your xmlns attribute.  In your case,

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
    xmlns:t="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    version="2.0">
```

You can also use the prefix "urn:jsptld:" to specify the location of a TLD.  For more details, see the section on "Declaring Tag Libraries" in http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPX3.html.